# Spritekit Interstitial Admob ios8

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, admob, interstitial

I have tried checking other related questions but it was unsuccessful. I am following the example code located [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/admob/InterstitialExample). The program runs on my iPhone successfully but when I go to first call the ad it gets hung up on    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];    . There is no error message it just stops running with that above line highlighted. I have tried running it in the GameViewController and in my actual sprite kit scene. Any help would be appreciated. The sample project that I downloaded runs perfectly.

GameViewController.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
-(void)createAndLoadInterstitial;
-(void)loadAd;
```

GameViewController.m

```
- (void)createAndLoadInterstitial {
self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-9726509502990875/8489925949";
self.interstitial.delegate = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Request test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
// an ad request is made.
request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" ];
[self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

}

```
-(void)loadAd {
if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
} else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Interstitial not ready"
                                message:@"The interstitial didn't finish loading or failed to load"
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Drat"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

}

GameScene.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GameViewController *GameViewController;
```

GameScene.m

```
//this is in -(void)gameOver which is called on contact call in -(void)didBeginContact
self.GameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[self.GameViewController createAndLoadInterstitial];
[self.GameViewController loadAd];
```

Comment: How you call ad in skscene? I have to see your codes for help.

Comment: You can't call like this from SKScene. Try to cocos2d example code, cocos2d is already available in your following example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your `ViewController`**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"showAd" object:nil];

- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"showAd"]) {
        if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
           [ self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Interstitial not ready"
                                message:@"The interstitial didn't finish loading or failed to load"
                               delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Drat"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
}
```

**In `yourSKScene` call with `this`**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAd" object:nil];
```

Comment: It is still getting hung up on the initial     self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init]; stops the program

Comment: Did you try cocos2d example?

Comment: I have it calling the methods but now every single time it goes to display the banner it isn't ready to be shown.

Comment: the test ad is presenting on the simulator but on my phone it is displaying the alert instead. Any reason why?

Comment: Spent another hour working on this. Phone froze so I rebooted and now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `-ObjC` to `Linker`

Below is the solution:

1. Click on your project name
2. Go to Build Setting tab
3. Search for name `linker`
4. Find Other Link Flags
5. Double click on your project name then click `+ button`
6. add `-ObjC`